# Is there a function that takes in a binary number and yields the corresponding decimal number, or vice versa?

Tags: functions, binary

For example,

f(10111010) = 186

f(101110101101001) = 23913

Correspondingly, is there an inverse function to this?

Comment: Your question defines the function perfectly.  As the function is a bijection, the inverse function is also well defined.  You are equating function and algorithm.  This is badly wrong-functions are *much* more general.  As long as one input gives one output you have a function.  There does not need to be a simple formula.  Here there is one.

Comment: Looks like the identity function to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a standard algorithm](http://cut-the-knot.org/recurrence/conversion.shtml) to convert between the representations of a number in different bases.

Answer (score 1):

The function exists, because you just defined it.  I believe what you meant to ask is, "does a simple formula exist for this function?"  I don't think that there is a formula much simpler than performing the algorithm to do the conversion.  I expect it would be a mess of fractions and floor functions and modulo reductions.

Comment: Also, this function operates on strings, not numbers, so it's unclear what sort of formula is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is defined such as:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{f} :  \{0,1\}^n & \longrightarrow \mathbb{N} \\[-1ex]
 (a_0,...,a_n) & \longmapsto \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} 2^k a_k
\end{align*}
$$